# Appear & Disappear Images using TimerControl , C#.net

Tags: timer

I have 3 Images (Image1, Image2, Image3),

Using a timer control with interval value of 5000, i.e 5second, I
want to accomplish the following:

- Initially, only Image1 is visible to the user middle of the form, i.e the 2 images 
  are set to be invisible.
- When load the form  appear and image1
  appears exact middle of the form
- After 5 seconds, the image1  disappear and image 2 appears  right side.
- After 5 seconds, the image2  disappear and image3 appears left side
- After 5 seconds, the image3 disappear and the image1 appear

I am setting timer control's Enable property to "True" in Design
time.
I am setting timer control's Interval property value to 5000 in
Design Time.

I assume that I do all the coding but not working only displaying two images

Can anyone help me code what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

**Very** "dirty" solution: keep a *status* variable from 0 to 2 (included) and increment  for each tick then show/hide each image with that.

On the timer tick event handler:

```
if (++_status > 2)
 _status = 0;

pctImage1.Visible = _status == 0;
pctImage2.Visible = _status == 1;
pctImage3.Visible = _stauts == 2;
```